# Investigate why Spring Boot service hangs (freeze) on service shutdown (SIGINT)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, xstream

I have a Spring Boot executable application - It's REST webservice. Service is working well, but when I try to gracefully shutdown it (by issuing process interrupt - SIGINT), service "hangs" and is still running. Here is log after shutdown command (red square stop button in Intellij IDEA):

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:36656', transport: 'socket'
2016-10-28 11:15:26.369  INFO 5429 --- [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@160ac7fb: startup date [Thu Oct 27 18:32:46 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

Red stop button changes to skull (when clicked, SIGKILL is sent and process is immediatelly dead)
[image]

Apparently, something (resource?) is blocking closing of spring context and exiting application normal way.

My question is: **How can I investigate what is wrong? What is the cause of blocking?**

Dependencies of project:

- spring-boot-starter-parent 1.4.1.RELEASE
- spring-boot-starter-web
- com.oracle:ojdbc6
- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream
- and some commons

Btw, service is running on Oracle Java "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)" and on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (and will run on production also)

I suspect xstream library, but I don't know how to find out. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You can try to use VisualVM to find the thread that is blocking.

Comment: @Gondy did you get answer of this?

Comment: @spandey15 Problem was with Oracle driver - It was waiting for data from database, but Oracle DB already killed the connection. We solved it by setting keep alive setting in datasource definition.